# Upgrade Django-cms from 3.2.3 to 3.5

Tags: django, django-cms

I try to upgrade a `django-cms` site from 3.2.3 to 3.5 but it doesn't work.
I upgrade version by version (from 3.2.3 to 3.3 then 3.3 to 3.4). 
It was OK until I upgrade from 3.4 to 3.5

I had multiples errors when I run `manage.py migrate` :

- Table cms_treenode doesn't exit
- Key is duplicated
- The column `node_id` doesn't exist.

(The errors are in migrations files, so I tried to modify them directly, so one error disappears and another appears, this is why I listed multiple errors)

Current versions: `Django=1.8.15`, `Postgres=9.5.14`

Does anyone upgrade from `django-cms 3.2` to `3.5` correctly without bugs?

[The result of 'manage.py makemigrations' command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwZ5E.jpg)

[The result of 'manage.py migrate' command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erPYq.jpg)

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you followed the upgrade instructions & ran the necessary migrations etc after each stage? http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/upgrade/3.5.html

Comment: Without any modification to the migration files, can you post the full traceback of the first error that is raised?

Comment: @markwalker_ yes I followed the documentation for the upgrade.

Comment: @Paulo I edit my post and I added the traceback of the commands after upgrading grom 3.4 to 3.5